# How to convert quadratic programming problem to matrix form

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming

I am new to this topic and am looking at an example I can't figure out.  Can someone please help explain how this example creates the matrices used in the solver?  Thanks!

[This is the PROBLEM](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/_images/math/223a4919c099dd62bf772f50fd693e7396682384.png)

> Minimize $2x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_1x_2 + x_1 + x_2,\quad$subject to:
>
> $x_1 \geq 0$
> $x_2 \geq 0$
> $x_1 + x_2 = 1$

ANSWER:
Matrix Form for solver:
Q = 
[4.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 2.0]

p = 
[1.0]
[1.0]

G = 
[-1.0, 0.0]
[0.0, -1.0]

h = 
[0.0]
[0.0]

A = [1.0, 1.0]

b = [1.0]

result = solve.qp(Q, p, G, h, A, b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to solve a quadratic program of the form:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & \frac{1}{2} x^T Q x + p^T x \\
& \text{subject to}
& & Gx \preceq h \\
&&& Ax = b
\end{aligned}
$$
Expand the objective function where $x = \left [x_1 \quad x_2 \right ]^T$ and you will see that

$$\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = (2x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_1x_2) + (x_1 + x_2)
$$.

Similarly, expand $Gx \preceq h$ and $Ax = b$ and you'll see that they are equivalent to $x_1,x_2 \ge 0$ and $x_1+x_2 = 1$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you! - your answer is elegant and extremely helpful